# LoadError: cannot load such file -- mime/types (LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redmine, redmine-plugins

I am trying to migrate a Redmine plugin to 5.x. And then I hit this error:

> LoadError: cannot load such file -- mime/types (LoadError)

The code is like:

```
# coding: utf-8
require 'nkf'
require 'csv'
require 'mime/types'
```

I tried gem install mime but the issue was still there.

Comment: Maybe you installed the wrong gem. You probably installed mime (v0.4.4) instead of mime-types (v3.5.2). Try `gem install mime-types`

Comment: No, that's not the case.

# gem list | grep mime
mime-types (3.5.2)
mime-types-data (3.2023.1205)
mini_mime (1.1.5)

Answer (score 1):

The issue got resolved.
I put mime-type in Gemfile and the issue is gone.
The issue can't fixed by manually installing mime-type.
This is a newbie issue.

Comment: Could you mark the question as accepted? It will help others and keep the open questions low. Regards